# Find computer names on a private network (with nmap?)

Tags: networking, nmap

On a LAN, I want to find out the names of all the connected computers using a cross-platform program, preferably nmap. I know I can do

```
nmap -sn xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24
```

(where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is a local IP address) to find hosts which are up, but how do I find the computers' hostnames? Do they broadcast this in a way that I can find using nmap?

**UPDATE:** It looks like Angry IP Scanner can do this. How does it do this? Can I replicate it with nmap?

Comment: which hostnames? DNS names? Ask your DNS server.

Comment: @ragnq nslookup doesn't give me hostnames, but Angry Port Scanner does. I'm trying to figure out how to do this with nmap and/or command line tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used nmap and other IP scanners such as Angry IP scanner. My observation was that Nmap used Reverse DNS to resolve hostnames, so for that to work the DNS server should have reverse pointer records for the hosts. I found that other scanners follow up a PTR Query with a Netbios Query.

If you are sure that all hosts on the target network are Windows hosts and that they have NETBIOS enabled, you can use [nbtscan tool](http://www.inetcat.net/software/nbtscan.html) to scan them.

Answer (score 3):

From Angry IP Scanner's FAQ ("[Hostnames not shown](https://angryip.org/faq/hostnames)"):

> Angry IP Scanners displays hostnames returned by your DNS (name)
> server, by doing a [reverse lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup). The server is provided the IP
> address and returns the hostname if it knows it.
>
> If some computer
> knows its own name, it doesn't mean that it has provided it the the
> network's DNS server. In other words, the name of the host as it knows
> it itself (the local name) and the name attached to the IP address
> (the global name) as it known by the DNS server may not always match.
>
> Very often, DNS queries will return some generic names, e.g.
> dhcp-12-13.superisp.com, especially in ISP networks.
>
> The names match
> in either of these cases:
>
> - Your computer has sent the name to the DHCP server from which it obtained the IP address and DHCP server has provided it to the local
>   DNS server
> - You have a static IP address and your local hostname is configured according to the rules that match global naming convention in your
>   network
> - Your host's TCP stack returns the local name if the local IP address is queried, not asking the global name

From Nmap's documentation ("[Host Discovery](http://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html)"):

> By default, Nmap still does [reverse-DNS resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) on the hosts to
> learn their names.

[Additional reading/info here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/basic-command-to-resolve-ip-to-hostname-582026/).

Comment: On the network I'm working on Angry IP Scanner shows me the hostnames, presumably by doing a reverse-DNS lookup. What you're saying is that nmap does a reverse-lookup too. But it's not displaying the hostnames. How can I get it to display the hostnames? Or is this the wrong tool for that job?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I have to specify `--system-dns` to get the names of the machines on the network. I'm not sure why this works. Maybe there is something unexpected in the way DNS is configured?

**UPDATE:** Actually, it works on one VLAN but not on another, but Angry IP Scanner works on both.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `nmap -A xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`
it should show the hostnames in the output. on my network i pipe it through grep to get just the info i want. ~ `grep -e 'scan report' -e 'Computer name'`